# How common is it for airlines to fly unauthorised flight paths?

Tags: airline-operations

With the revelation that flight QZ8501 did not have permission to fly the route on the day it crashed, I'm wondering how common an occurrence this is.

Is it something that all airlines do every now and then and is actually not a serious thing? Just seems it would hardly be an oversight - as you'd think since they have to advertise tickets, they would've planned to take that route on that day months in advance. It should be a fairly straight forward thing to check whether they were authorised to fly then.

Comment: If you look at the weather radar picture [here](http://avherald.com/h?article=47f6abc7&opt=4096), one reason could be to circumvent a tropical storm. This cannot be planned days in advance and is one of the reasons why airliners take plenty of reserve fuel for their trips. It might not be common, but normal.

Comment: It is totally unclear from the question or from the media I've read what was unauthorised about the flight or what kind of authorisation was missing. So it is impossible to answer how common that is.

Comment: Flightplans are *plans*. They can be, and often are, amended at any time, either at the request of the pilot or by ATC.

Comment: The permission you refer to was regarding route rights.  It flew that route often, just not on that day.  The permit was for Monday, Tuesday, Thursday and Saturday,.  So far, this is supposition since it has been reported only in newspapers whose track record of reporting aviation matters accurately is very poor.

Comment: looking at [this image on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia_AirAsia_Flight_8501#mediaviewer/File:Air_Asia_QZ8501_Flight_Path_and_Satellite_Imagery.jpg) it looks like the plane lost contact when it entered the red (colder) zone, just [twelve minutes](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/12/28/world/asia/airasia-flight-qz8501-time-line/index.html) after asking permission to turn left.

Comment: @Simon - Hi, yes this is what I'm referring to. Regardless of whether the AirAsia did fly without this permit or not, I think it's still a valid question whether airlines do indeed 1) fly a route without any permit 2) fly a route on days which is not included in the permit

Comment: Having read the Wiki article, it states that Air Asia doesn't have permission to fly that route on Sunday, and I take that to be the question - How often do airlines fly routes on days they don't have permission to? At least, that's the question I would ask.